# Vert.x Unit Test a Verticle that does not implement the start method with future

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, vert.x

I'm new to Vert.x and just stumbled about a problem.
I've the following Verticle:

```
public class HelloVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

    String greetingName = config().getString("greetingName", "Welt");
    String greetingNameEnv = System.getenv("GREETING_NAME");
    String greetingNameProp = System.getProperty("greetingName");

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.get("/hska").handler(routingContext -> {
        routingContext.response().end(String.format("Hallo %s!", greetingName));
    });
    router.get().handler(routingContext -> {
        routingContext.response().end("Hallo Welt");
    });

    vertx
            .createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router::accept)
            .listen(8080);
  }
}
```

I want to unit test this verticle but i dont know how to wait for the verticle to be deployed.

```
@Before
public void setup(TestContext context) throws InterruptedException {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    JsonObject config = new JsonObject().put("greetingName", "Unit Test");

    vertx.deployVerticle(HelloVerticle.class.getName(), new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config));
}
```

when i setup my test like this i have to add a `Thread.sleep` after the deploy call, to make the tests be executed after some time of watiting for the verticle.

I heared about Awaitability and that it should be possible to wait for the verticle to be deployed with this library. But I didn't find any examples of how to use Awaitability with vertx-unit and the `deployVerticle` method.

Could anyone bring some light into this?

Or do i really have to hardcode a sleep timer after calling the `deployVerticle`-Method in my tests?

**Have a look into the comments of the accepted answer**

Comment: Can you change the verticle code? Because using the start method with `Future` and complete the `TestContext` when deployment is done is the easiest and most robust solution.

Comment: Yes, since its just an example for learning purpose. But it kinda disturbs me, that i have to change production code to fit tests. In my opinion it should be the other way aroung :(

Comment: I suggest you read the Javadoc for start method with no args _"If your verticle does a simple, synchronous start-up then override this method and put your start-up code in there."_ It seems to me you're using the wrong method in the first place.

Comment: Yeah i choosed my example really badly.. But would the fact that the start method does a synchronous task change anything in my test? i still would have to wait unit `deployVerticle` is finished, which is asynchronous itself

Comment: Not it wouldn't. Even when the start method is empty, deployment is an asynchronous task. That is why you have `TestContext` as a param of your `@Before` method. As shown in the blog post, you need to use `deployVerticle` with `context.asyncAssertSuccess()`.

Comment: Correct. And this only works with the `start(Future future)`-Method. Seems that override `start()` is NEVER reasonable since it will result in code that is not easily testable.

Comment: Not, it does work with the start method as well (if it performs no asynchronous tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to implement `start(Future future)` instead of just `start()`. Then you need to add a callback handler (`Handler<AsyncResult<HttpServer>> listenHandler`) to the `listen(...)` call — which then resolves the `Future` you got via `start(Future future)`.

Vert.x is highly asynchronous — and so is the start of an Vert.x HTTP server. In your case, the Verticle would be fully functional when the HTTP server is successfully started. Therefore, you need implement the stuff I mentioned above.

Second you need to tell the `TestContext` that the asynchronous deployment of your Verticle is done. This can be done via another callback handler (`Handler<AsyncResult<String>> completionHandler`). Here is [blog post](http://vertx.io/blog/unit-and-integration-tests/) shows how to do that.
The deployment of a Verticle is always asynchronous even if you implemented the plain `start()` method. So you should always use a `completionHandler` if you want to be sure that your Verticle was successfully deployed before test.

So, no you don't need to and you definitely shouldn't hardcode a sleep timer in any of your Vert.x applications. Mind [The Golden Rule - Don’t Block the Event Loop](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule).

**Edit:**

If the initialisation of your Verticle is synchronous you should overwrite the plain `start()` method — [like it's mentioned in the docs](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/AbstractVerticle.html#start--):

> If your verticle does a simple, synchronous start-up then override this method and put your start-up code in there.

If the initialisation of your Verticle is asynchronous (e.g. deploying a Vert.x HTTP server) you should overwrite `start(Future future)` and complete the `Future` when your asynchronous initialisation is finished.

Comment: Yeah i know that it's possible if i implement start(Future future). But i couldn't believe that vert.x provides methods that aren't easily testable. Seems that start() is just useless..

Comment: The plain start method is only useful if you deploy a verticle which doesn't starts something asynchronous. But the start of a verticle is always asynchronous with a Future or without.

Comment: And just for the record... In your question you ask about how to wait for a Verticle to be successfully deployed, didn't you?

Comment: "Vert.x Unit Test a Verticle that does not implement the start method with future" is the title of the question

Comment: *Edit:* The deployment of a Verticle is always asynchronous even if you implemented the plain `start()` method. So you should always use a completionHandler if you want to be sure that your Verticle was successfully deployed before test.

Comment: In your case you need to change the Verticle implementation (which is faulty). If that is not possible you should at least wait for a successful deployment and wait a little or check till the port is open.

Comment: So to be clear the production code is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: Is it wrong just because it does not implement the start(Future future)? Or how should i fix this? Sorry if my question sounds stupid, but i don't really get the use of start(). The example above is just an example for learning purpose. Of course i would implement it with a Future in a real world application, but i try to find out when it could be useful to implement start() and how to properly test it

Comment: Yes, it is wrong because it doesn't implement `start(Future future)`. That's needed because you depend on the asynchronous deployment of the HTTP server inside the `start` method.
The plain `start()` only makes sense if you don't depend on stuff which happens asynchronous or if the `start` method doesn't do anything asynchronous at all.

Comment: Your tests need to wait for the HTTP server. Therefore you need to tell the `TestContext` when the HTTP server is ready.

Comment: Makes sense so far. But you Said, `deployVerticle` is asynchronous itself, so i would have to wait until it's finished even if i'd do synchronous stuff inside the start method, wouldn't i?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As I said Vert.x is highly asynchronous – all the way down!

Comment: Ok thank you for your patient answers. In conclusion i would say, that it's NEVER good to implement start() instead of start(Future future) since it will result in hardly testable Code. If you aggree with that, you maybe add this to your answer. Then i'll accept it

Comment: No, that's not exactly true. You can implement `start()` if the stuff you are doing is synchronous. But in your case you are doing something asynchronous.

Comment: Added a paragraph about `start()` and `start(Future future)` as well as there usage.